# Type casting from an Object

Tags: java

I have some code in Java as follows:

```
private Object addVertex(String label, int posX, int posY) {
    Vertex newVertex = new Vertex();
    this.getModel().beginUpdate();
    try {
        newVertex = insertVertex(parent, null, label, posX, posY, 80, 30);
    }
    finally {
        this.getModel().endUpdate();
    }
    return newVertex;
}
```

That code wont work because of a type mismatch, insertVertex will return an Object, but I get a type mismatch since it can't convert from Object to Vertex (which is an object I created).

Firstly, how come that can't work, since the object Vertex inherits Object by default surely you should be able to do that.

Also, if I try and type cast the Object to a Vertex as follows

```
newVertex = (Vertex) insertVertex(parent, null, label, posX, posY, 80, 30);
```

I get an error saying I can't make that conversion.

Comment: Can you provide that error ? I presume it's a ClassCastException

Comment: from the name "insertVertex", it sounds like that method is a void method, and will insert the object into parent (instead of returning it)...but of course thats just wild speculation - please provide more info as afk asks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vertex` inherits from `Object`, but not the other way round. Basically you're trying to do:

```
Object tmp = insertVertex(...);
newVertex = tmp;
```

You can't assign an `Object` reference to `newVertex` because the latter is of type `Vertex`.

Now, with your cast it *should* be okay, so long as `insertVertex` is genuinely returning a `Vertex` at execution time. Please give details of *exactly* what error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
Object insertResult = insertVertex(parent, null, label, posX, posY, 80, 30);
if(insertResult instanceof Vertex){
   newVertex = (Vertex)insertResult;
}
```

If you get the default implementation the returned type is not a Vertex object.

**The insertVertex method has to return an Object which extends from Vertex!**

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cast the result of insertVertex to whatever you want. It may fail at runtime, but if you know that it will always be a Vertex, then it should not fail. As Markus suggests, you can use instanceof to test that.

As an aside, the code looks strange in the you create a new Vertex and assign it to the newVertex variable, but then don't pass that reference anywhere?

Comment: Actually, even the compiler will reject casts that it knows cannot succeed because the type that's being cast is from a different inheritance hierarchy than the type it's being cast to. The compiler error is "Cannot cast X to Y" in that case - perhaps this is what saralk is encountering.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert Object into an instance of Vertex, because Object is a superclass of Vertex, not the other way around.

Can you modify InsertVertex to return a Vertex object instead of an Object? There's really no reason not to. Otherwise, you will have to manually cast the Object to the Vertex object through a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a Fruit to a Banana. The Banana is more specific than a Fruit, it's a subclass of Fruit. You can do the opposite, `Fruit f = new Banana();`

This is what is happening here. If your `insertVertex` returns an `Object` it can only be assigned to another `Object`. If you cast it to `Vertex` and you get an error, then your `insertVertex` method must be declaring another type of `Object` that is not a subclass of `Vertex`.

Answer (score 0):

Well for the definition of the function looks that what you want is to return Object, so probably you dont need to cast to Vertex and just define newVertex as an Object. However it looks that in any case you will need to do the casting in another function. It sounds to me that the cast should work and if not, please send the exceptions that have been generating.